# Python3 create list

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Sum Qo'D tob 'e' SoH
jeD ngeH maHaD 'e roj message maHa might consider
leaving SoH yong roj 'baD yInD SoHDa Haup lives
jeD ngeH maHaD 'e roj message maHa might consider
```

How can I convert it to this list:

```
[['Sum', 'Qo'D', 'tob', "'e'", 'SoH'],
['jeD', 'ngeH', 'maHaD', "'e", 'roj', 'maHa', 'might'],
['leaving', 'SoH', 'yong', 'roj', "'baD", 'yInD', 'SoHDa', 'Haup']
['jeD', 'ngeH', 'maHaD', "'e", 'roj', 'message', 'maHa', 'might', 'consider']]
```

For example `list[0]` is `['Sum', 'Qo'D', 'tob', "'e'", 'SoH']`
or `list[0][0]` is `Sum`.

Comment: see: [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Answer (score 1):

if:

```
text="""Sum Qo'D tob 'e' SoH
jeD ngeH maHaD 'e roj message maHa might consider
leaving SoH yong roj 'baD yInD SoHDa Haup lives
jeD ngeH maHaD 'e roj message maHa might consider"""
```

Do that with a oneliner (using a listcomp):

```
print([line.split() for line in text.splitlines()])
```

result:

```
[['Sum', "Qo'D", 'tob', "'e'", 'SoH'], 
['jeD', 'ngeH', 'maHaD', "'e", 'roj', 'message', 'maHa', 'might', 'consider'], 
['leaving', 'SoH', 'yong', 'roj', "'baD", 'yInD', 'SoHDa', 'Haup', 'lives'],
['jeD', 'ngeH', 'maHaD', "'e", 'roj', 'message', 'maHa', 'might', 'consider']]
```

Edit: Jim suggested an alternative using `map`, which makes sense here since we don't need a `lambda` to provide to `map` (we already can use `str.split`):

```
list(map(str.split, text.splitlines()))
```

(`list` is required because python 3 `map` returns an iterator)

Comment: or: `list(map(str.split, text.split('\n')))`.

Comment: yes. I forgot about `map` (on purpose) since python 3, since you have to create a list out of it if it's your final output. I noticed that `map`, `filter`, have been really less used since, and listcomps used instead. All solutions that I posted here with `map` didn't get upvoted, concurrent solutions with listcomps did...

Comment: Haha, I still find map visually appealing, either way, presenting both is what I always try and do :-)

Comment: yes, proposing both cannot hurt. But I'll stop before `lambda` because it really make people run away :)